# TypeScript declaration for untyped module that allows importing any named member from it

Tags: typescript

### Background

I have a tRPC-style (although not using tRPC exactly) TypeScript project setup, where modules under "client" are allowed to import files under certain folder "api" under "backend". Backend and client are separate projects containing their own tsconfigs. When checking the client-project, I'd like TypeScript to read exports from the "api" folder, but not validate them and their imports further, because that is already done separately by the backend project's type checking.
I am aware of the "project references" -feature, but I'd like to not go through that route, because, as far as I know, it'd then require that the backend project is built first to be able to type check client.

Also, one approach would've been to basically annotate all the "api" folders with `// @ts-nocheck`, but there doesn't seem to be a way to do this with tsconfig. I don't want to add `@ts-nocheck` comment in there, because I still do want to type check them when we type check the backend project.

Instead, my approach is to configure the client project so that any imports to other backend folders outside of the "api" folder are typed as any, so that their correctness isn't a concern for the client-project's type checking. I'm close to this, but there's one little problem to solve still.

### The approach

I'm configuring the client project so that all imports to other backend-folders than "api" basically point to this untyped definition:

```js
// backend.d.ts

declare module 'backend' {
  const moduleExports: any
  export = moduleExports
}
```

This works great, as long as I use either default imports or namespaced imports:

```js
import * as foo from 'backend'

foo.bar.baz // no error, good
```

```js
import foo from 'backend'

foo.bar.baz // no error, good
```

### The problem

However, this definition still doesn't seem to allow named member imports

```js
import {foo} from 'backend'
// Error: Module '"backend"' has no exported member 'foo'. ts(2305)
```

Is there a way to make TypeScript allow this style of importing untyped members of the modules, without needing to explicitly specify each member of the "backend" module?